# Re-translating pypy for old CPU

Tags: python, windows, windows-xp, pypy

I am running Windows XP SP3 32-bit on a PIII box with 384MB of RAM.

I have downloaded and installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) (aka vcredist_x86.exe) using the link from the pypy.org installation page.

I have downloaded and unzipped pypy-2.5.0-win32.zip from pypy.org. I have added the location of the new pypy directory to my PATH variable.

I can open a CMD window and type pypy.exe and pypy starts to run and then throws up an error message "Old CPU with no SSE2 support, cannot continue. You need to re-translate with '--jit-backend=x86-without sse2' ".  The same happens if I click on pypy.exe in Explorer.

I expect it is true that my CPU is too old but I do not understand from the pypy documentation how to re-translate pypy with '--jit-backend=x86-without sse2'.

I imagine one route is to buy and learn how to use a Windows C Compiler.  If that is right what is the easiest and simplest compiler to use ?  I have used Fortran compilers on PC's in the past so I have a little experience. However, for me, this will be a one off exercise simply to get pypy running on my PC so I can play with some pypy code that someone else has written.  It is probably beyond me, or it would take me weeks, to completely rebuild pypy from the entire set of source code.

Is there anywhere that I could find a pre-compiled '--jit-backend=x86-without sse2' version for my old box ?  Alternatively I can see all the old pypy uploads, can anyone tell me how far back I need to go to get a pre-compiled version without JIT ?  At random I picked pypy-1.9 and installed that but it produced the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the web page with: "If your CPU is really, really old, it may be a x86-32 without SSE2.
We could at some point make a PyPy with a JIT without SSE2 ---ask us
on IRC if you really want to know more--- but note that your machine
is probably low-spec enough that running CPython on it is a better
idea in the first place."

For fun's value I am making a Windows version of PyPy 2.5 without the JIT: it should show up in a while at http://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/release-2.5.x/ under a name starting with "pypy-c-nojit-...".  Note that it will be slower than CPython with almost no benefit.  Just use CPython.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your fun build runs perfectly on my machine and has got me started with pypy without lots of mucking around with compilers (or CPython).  Now I can start to work out what the code I have is doing and adapt it to my problem.  If you ever do a JIT-without-SSE2 please let me know.